# Is there a given function, property or method which can get a size in following case?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I rotate a UILabel 30 degree.

In this case, I would like to get a bound size.

Is there a given feature? (function, property, method, etc..)

```
    UILabel *uiLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)] autorelease];
    uiLabel.text = @"UILabel Text";
    uiLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat) (-M_PI/4));

    CGSize rotatedBound = uiLabel.?????
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` member of the `frame` property reflects the new container size:

```
CGSize rotatedBound = uiLabel.frame.size;
```

Comment: @user1182731 and H2CO3 makes soda water enjoyable :P (thanks)